# English translation of Brahms' essay: "Octaven und Quinten"?

Tags: theory, history, classical-music, musicology, romantic-period

I am now doing some research on Brahm's essay, *Octaven u. Quinten*. I cannot read German, so I cannot do anything with the original manuscript. I have read some secondary sources about this essay, but they only summarise the main topics without going into details.

Is there an English translation to this essay, *Octaven u. Quinten*? It does not have to be an exact translation. I am just looking for an article that includes Brahms's main ideas, including exactly what types of consecutive fifths are considered appropriate or inappropriate by Brahms.

Comment: There isn't even the German original text to find (as Pdf or downloadable book)

I found a lot of secondary literature and especially this here:

http://www.schenkerdocumentsonline.org/profiles/work/entity-003331.html

Schenkers handwritten letters copied and translated in English. 

Could this help? Do you have an digital copy of the original you could share?

Answer (score 1):

The English wikipedia has a reference to a printed book:

> Oktaven und Quinten [translated by Paul Mast 1971](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Oktaven_und_Quinten.html?id=lTZpXwAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)

Comment: The most convenient location of this translation is likely Volume 5 (1980) of *The Music Forum*.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't even the German original text to find (as Pdf or downloadable book)

I found a lot of secondary literature and especially this here:

http://www.schenkerdocumentsonline.org/profiles/work/entity-003331.html

Schenkers handwritten letters copied and translated in English.

Maybe you have access to this site:

https://academic.oup.com/ml/article-abstract/73/1/48/1220490/?redirectedFrom=PDF

Comment: I fail to see, how this answers the question, given that the OP already mentioned studying secondary sources.

Comment: secondary sources very often contain translated  quotations of whole passages. Well, I have overseen that OP has already found some secondary sources as I was looking - in my own interests - for the original and a translation. I have found Paul Mast too, but if OP can't afford to buy it? May be one of the sources above OP didn't find as OP also didn't find Paul Mast. :)